# Error MSB6006 when building Native Activity app Intel INDE

Tags: android, c++, ant, msbuild

I'm following the "getting started" tutorial on the Intel website which guides you through setting up an Native Activity android app in Visual Studio (2013) with the Intel INDE software kit. However, when I start the emulator and build the app, I get the following error:

Error 28 error MSB6006: "C:\Intel\INDE\IDEintegration\ANT\bin\ant.bat" exited with code 9020.   C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\Android\Microsoft.Cpp.Android.targets    353 5   HelloWorld

Anyone familiar with this? I can't find anywhere how to solve this.

Hope someone can help me soon :)

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are having the same problem, I found the answer myself and wrote it down here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/558108

Hope I can help some of you guys with it as well!